# Markov chain identity

Tags: markov-process

Consider $P(X,Y)$ discrete and two chains $X \rightarrow  Z$ and $X \rightarrow Z'$.
Does then following inequality hold?

$$
P(X,Y,Z) = P(X,Y,Z') = P(X,Y)
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no. We have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X,Y,Z) = \mathbb{P}(Z|X,Y)\mathbb{P}(X,Y)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X,Y,Z') = \mathbb{P}(Z'|X,Y)\mathbb{P}(X,Y)
\end{align}
which **does not satisfy** $\mathbb{P}(Z|X,Y)=\mathbb{P}(Z'|X,Y)$ in general. However, you did not specify all dependencies between $X,Y,Z,Z'$. For equality to hold, we could satisfy $\mathbb{P}(Z|X,Y)=\mathbb{P}(Z'|X,Y)=1$ if $Z=f(X,Y)$ and $Z'=g(X,Y)$ for invertible functions $f,g$. The idea here is that knowing $X$ or $Y$ should give enough information to reconstruct $Z$ and $Z'$ perfectly, and hence, their conditional probabilities are one.

Comment: is it possible to Establishment Establishment relationship between $P(X,Y,Z)$ and $P(X,Y,Z')$?

Comment: At first glance, the two relationships I saw were $\mathbb{P}(X,Y,Z)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(Z|X,Y)}{\mathbb{P}(Z'|X,Y)} \mathbb{P}(X,Y,Z')$ and $|\mathbb{P}(X,Y,Z)-\mathbb{P}(X,Y,Z')|=\mathbb{P}(X,Y)|\mathbb{P}(Z|X,Y)-\mathbb{P}(Z'|X,Y)|$.

Comment: I have managed to specify better the problem I want to address. Would you mind checking this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4330654/identity-for-special-case-of-markov-chain